# Docker cloud repository push: access to the requested resource is not authorized on Fedora 23

Tags: docker, docker-registry, fedora-23, tutum

I've just come over from tutum and and am trying to deploy to a docker cloud repository. I've created the repository and have tagged an existing image:

```
docker tag deploy foo/rtb
```

When I attempt to push my tagged image up like so:

```
docker push foo/rtb
```

I get this:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/foo/rtb] (len: 0)
18118bb6b8ef: Preparing 
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

The repository exists and I've logged in to docker. Is there something I'm missing?

Interestingly enough, if I try to delete the image I get an error like this:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 18118bb6b8ef 
(must be forced) - image is referenced in one or more repositories
Error: failed to remove images: [18118bb6b8ef]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been using docker 1.9.1. That's the version in the Fedora 23 repo.

The kind folks at docker tech support recommended I upgrade to the latest 1.10.3

Upgrading then doing

```
docker logout
```

followed by

```
docker login
```

fixed everything up.

Comment: Yeah, one 1.10 was breaking things for people — it was in updates-testing, but then reverted. We're exploring a way to install multiple versions in parallel and let you decide as a config option. See [discussion here](https://lists.projectatomic.io/projectatomic-archives/atomic-devel/2016-March/msg00122.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tag your image ?

```
docker build --tag docker.io/<yourdockerhubname>/<appname> .    
docker build --tag docker.io/moskalr/rtb  .


docker push  docker.io/<yourdockerhubname>/<appname>
docker push  docker.io/moskalr/rtb
```

the push should respond with something which mentions the dockerhub image name

Comment: see my post. I am logged in